# Display Text in Text Area Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm new to Django and looking for a way to display terms and condition paragraphs in the Form Text area to view them on my home.html.

Text for TextArea: 
To use the Online Services through U.S. Bank, you must:
• Be a U.S. Bank customer with an eligible account;
• Have and maintain valid log-in credentials (including a personal ID and password) for Online Services, which may be provided and revoked in our sole discretion;
• Have and maintain a valid email address;
• Agree to electronically accept this Agreement and notices regarding this Agreement; and
• Use Online Services in accordance with the terms of this Agreement.
Use of certain Online Services may require additional accounts or other eligibility requirements.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in Advance

My From:

```
class AccountModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AccountModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    Balance = forms.IntegerField(initial=1000, disabled=True)
    Stmtcb = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label="Receive Monthly Statement")
    tandc= forms.CharField(label="Terms & Conditions",widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows":5, "cols":20, "class":"tcta", "name":"tandc"}))

    class Meta:
        ACCT_TYPE = [
    ('CA','Checking'),
    ('SA','Savings'),
    ('IA','Investment'),
]
        model = Account
        exclude = ("customer",)
        labels = {
            "Account_Number": "Account Number ",
            "Account_Type": "Account Type",
            "Balance": "Balance",
        }
        widgets = {
            "Account_Type": forms.Select(choices=ACCT_TYPE)
        }
```

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post">
     <table>
         {{ form.as_table }}
         <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
     {% csrf_token %}
     </form>
```

Comment: what text area? are you talking about a form? show us your view/template. Why can't you just add this text to the HTML? Why is the specific text relevant and are you showing it?

Comment: Yes form text area.

Comment: Then explain a bit more the context of what you're trying to do. Are you letting your user edit this text? Is this intended to be a placeholder or initial value for the form field? You have to give context to your problem.

Comment: @dirkgroten I just want to display the text mentioned above for the user. It should not be editable, Thanks

Comment: Then why are you trying to display it in a form field? A form field is for editing. Why not just add it in your template?

Comment: @dirkgroten Can u just help me how I can add that in my template?

Comment: If you just want to display the t&c then just add a `<p>To use the online services...</p>` somewhere in your HTML. It's just HTML!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a form where your users **accept** the terms and conditions, then the form field should be a `BooleanField` not a `CharField`, because you only want to verify that they **check the box**. So replace your `tandc` field like this:

```
tandc = forms.BooleanField(label="To use the online services...")
```

Then in your form validation check that `self.cleaned_data['tandc']` is `True`.

Comment: I just want to display the paragraph to the user...So i used the char field.
How can I display the whole paragraph?? I mean where should I pass it?

Comment: Why do you need to "pass it". Just add it to your HTML using plain HTML. Wrap it in a <div> or <p> or <td> or whatever is appropriate for how you want to display it.

Comment: Then add a <tr> and <td> above the submit button

Comment: Yes Worked, Thanks